# Pytesseract / Recoginizing chars + digits + spaces

Tags: python, python-tesseract

i would like to recognize some text (with digits and spaces) from a image using the following code:

```
erg = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

Generally this works fine with that but i also get character i don´t want like Ô

```
ÔAU OPTRONICS CORPORATION

() Preliminary Specification
(V) Final Specification
Module 18.5" Color TFT-LCD
Model Name (G18SHANOT.O
Customer Date ÔApproved by Date
Crystal Hsieh 2016/06/29
Approved by Propared by
```

So i tried to whitelist tesseract using the following code instead:

```
workString =f'-c tessedit\_char\_whitelist={string.digits}(){string.ascii\_letters}' 
erg = pytesseract.image\_to\_string(img, config=workString)
```

With that i get the following text - so it seems that Ô is not outputted - but unfortunately have no spaces anymore -

AUOPTRONICSCORPORATION

```
()ProliminarySpecification
(V)FinalSpecification
Module 185ColorTFTLCD
ModelName (G18SHANOTO
Customer Date Approvedby Date
CrstalHsieh 2016(06)29
Approvedby Proparedby
```

Is there any way to whitelist the characters and digits but also still output the spaces / blanks?

Comment: Have you tried adding string.whitespace to your whitelist?

Comment: Hello - i tried but also with that i get the output without spaces / blanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
config = f"-c tessedit_char_whitelist='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.#-:/ '"
```

Try this. I added a space within the inner quotes when I was having a similar issue, but this approach worked for me (space is the last character in the string). Feel free to add/remove any characters you want tesseract to include/exclude.